# How to set thermal throttling lowest CPU clock on Linux?

Tags: linux, thinkpad, intel-core-i7, throttling

I am having huge problems with thermal throttling on my Thinkpad T420 with Core i7 and Nvidia Quadro. When the throttling starts I get the kernel message:

```
[42544.677294] [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[42672.480582] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1023)
[42672.480587] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1023)
[42672.480591] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1023)
[42672.480594] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1023)
```

Problem got really on my nerves when I recently started doing some gaming. After literally couple of minutes the game can become unplayable. I have partially solved the problem after putting a limit on maximal clock frequency:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3; do echo 2000000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq;done
```

However, when the throttling starts on its own it sets the clocks to mere 800Mhz and I am sure 1.6Ghz would be enough to cool down the cpus. Any ideas how to set the throttle lowest clock?

Comment: Better check the cooling of the machine, it shouldn't go into overheating at all.

Comment: Well, actually I read that those Core i7 can get pretty hot by themselves. They are not designed to work at maximum frequencies for prolonged amounts of time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make a couple of scripts to rejig power settings for your task at hand.

I have a script for 2400MHz, 1600MHz, 800MHz - 2200MHz and 800MHz

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 0
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 1
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 2
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 3
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 4
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 5
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 6
sudo cpufreq-set -g conservative -d 1600MHz -u 1600MHz -c 7
```

You need to install cpufreq-set before hand:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```